# set ImageView style programatically don't working properly

Tags: android, imageview, styles, tablelayout

I have TableLayout whith ImageViews.

```
         <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                >

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


                    <ImageView
                        style="@style/image_view_style"
                        android:id="@+id/textView12"
                        android:background="@drawable/triangle"
                        android:src="@drawable/button_yes"
                        >
                    </ImageView>

                    <ImageView
                        style="@style/image_view_style"
                        android:src="@drawable/button_yes"
                        android:id="@+id/textView13">
                    </ImageView>


                    <ImageView
                        style="@style/image_view_style"
                        android:src="@drawable/button_yes"
                        android:id="@+id/textView14">
                    </ImageView>

                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/textView21"
                        style="@style/image_view_style"
                        >
                    </ImageView>

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/textView22"
                        style="@style/image_view_style"
                        android:src="@drawable/button_no">
                    </ImageView>

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/textView23"
                        android:src="@drawable/button_yes"
                        style="@style/image_view_style">
                    </ImageView>
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/textView41"
                        style="@style/image_view_style"
                        android:cropToPadding="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/button_no">
                    </ImageView>

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/textView42"
                        style="@style/image_view_style"
                        android:src="@drawable/button_yes">
                    </ImageView>


                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
```

this is image_view_style.xml
dimen/Image_view_width=80 and dimen/image_view_height=80

```
<style name="image_view_style">
    <item name="android:layout_width">@dimen/image_view_width</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">@dimen/image_view_height</item>
    <item name="android:padding">30dp</item>
    <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
</style>
```

When I ran tha app, then it's all right.[app screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cESpP.jpg)
But then, I get this Tablelayout, and set it's content programatically. But the images width and height that I get in the end do not match with previous style.
[app screen after setting ImageView programatically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kfi23.jpg)

Can you tell me why and how fix it?

```
    TableLayout visitTableLayout = (TableLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);
   visitTableLayout.removeAllViewsInLayout();
                     ...
 TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(getContext());
        tableRow.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                     ...
                        ImageView columnImageView = new ImageView(getContext());
                    columnImageView = (ImageView) getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.image_view_template_for_visit_table, null);
                    columnImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_no);
                    columnImageView.setTag(R.string.column_tag, columsInThisRow);
                    columnImageView.setTag(R.string.student_tag, i);
                    tableRow.addView(columnImageView, columsInThisRow - 1);
                         ...
                     visitTableLayout.addView(tableRow, i);
```

image_view_style_for_visit_table.xml

```
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
style="@style/image_view_style"/>
```

Comment: What do you mean by previous style? Is the size of the image not right?

Comment: @Pztar Yes, the size of image not right. Compare two screens of app.

Comment: It's not very easy to see that. I don't see you post the `LayoutParams` for your `ImageView` anywhere so it will default on it's own. Can you post the code for `image_view_template_for_visit_table`

Comment: try `getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.image_view_template_for_visit_table, tableRow, false);`

Comment: @Pztar it's help me. Thank you very much.